# Search Scope with Rule on TaxonomyField

Tags: search, taxonomy, search-scope

I've got a Termset for the corporate defined Taxonomy.

Now I need to define a search scope that will limit my search results to content that has been tagged with particular values of this taxonomy.

The scope rules for property query allow only for = filters, which means (I think) that I needed to add an include rule for each taxonomy value that I want to cover.

I don't seem to get what would be the correct format to define this value in the scope rules. I've tried the full path (Level1Tax:Level2Tax), just the final value (Level2Tax), Composed with ID (Level2Tax:TermID)... Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions, or any hint on what DB table I should take a peek at to see how the crawler is storing these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The correct format is Level1Tax:Level2Tax.

What was missing was that you need to do a full crawl before using a new managed property, incremental will not pick up your new property, and your scopes will keep returning empty.

Also, use the properties that have only the label/Path without any IDs. 
Crawled properties that include termIds will also have TaxonomyHiddenList.Id (ListID;#Label|TermID) which is not very helpfull since the list ID will be different on evey Site Collection.

It feels strange to answer my own question :-P
Maybe an admin can just delete it?
Cheers